# Reproduce the infinite loop with overriden Equals

Tags: c#

Recently I decided to play around with overriding the `Equals` method. I used mainly the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx) guideline (the updated one I believe). So my implementation end up like this:

```
public class EqualityCheck
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (null == obj)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //If obj is on of the expected type return false
        EqualityCheck ec = obj as EqualityCheck;
        if (null == ec)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //return true if the fields match. This is the place where we can decide what combination should be unique
        return (Age == ec.Age) && (Name == ec.Name) && (DateOfBirth == ec.DateOfBirth);

    }

    public bool Equals(EqualityCheck ec)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false:
        if (ec == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return (Age == ec.Age) && (Name == ec.Name);
    }
    //How to implement GetHashCode for complex object?      
}
```

And also one child class:

```
public class EqualityCheckChild : EqualityCheck
{
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        // If parameter cannot be cast to ThreeDPoint return false:
        EqualityCheckChild ec1 = obj as EqualityCheckChild;
        if (ec1 == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return base.Equals(obj) && Height == ec1.Height;
    }

    public bool Equals(EqualityCheckChild ec1)
    {
        // Return true if the fields match:
        return base.Equals((EqualityCheck)ec1) && Height == ec1.Height;
    }
    public static bool operator ==(EqualityCheckChild a, EqualityCheckChild b)
    {
        if (Equals(a, b))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (a == null || b == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return a.DateOfBirth == b.DateOfBirth && a.Name == b.Name;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(EqualityCheckChild a, EqualityCheckChild b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
}
```

I think this is what MSDN shows as implementation, just with removed casts.

I am using `VS2015` and `.NET 4.5.2`. VS marked the casting as redundant, that's when I look up what's the issue with this. I've read about the possible infinity loop and just out of curiosity I decided to recreate it with the code above. However I can't reproduce it.

Since this is not copy-paste code. At least not literally. I wrote it by hand trying to understand what I am doing so I guess it's possible to have some mismatch with the original code which leads to this. But still my question remains - how to reproduce the problem which is also mentioned in the MSDN article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt to compare an instance of `EqualityCheckChild` to null.

```
EqualityCheckChild foo = new EqualityCheckChild();
Console.WriteLine(foo == null);
```

This code snippet will cause a StackOverflowException, because in the `operator==` method, `if (a == null || b == null)` calls itself.

Comment: Thanks, That really leads to infinite loop. Is there any way to get into this situation by calling `Equals`?